# Random row selection in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, random

Is there a way to select random rows from a DataFrame in Pandas.

In R, using the car package, there is a useful function `some(x, n)` which is similar to head but selects, in this example, 10 rows at random from x.

I have also looked at the slicing documentation and there seems to be nothing equivalent.

#### Update

Now using version 20. There is a sample method.

```
df.sample(n)
```

Comment: If you are looking to sample where the size is greater than the original, use `df.sample(N, replace=True)`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052386/sampling-rows-with-sample-size-greater-than-length-of-dataframe/54052396#54052396).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import random

def some(x, n):
    return x.ix[random.sample(x.index, n)]
```

**Note:** As of Pandas v0.20.0, `ix` [has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) in favour of `loc` for label based indexing.

Comment: Thanks @eumiro. I also worked out that `df.ix[np.random.random_integers(0, len(df), 10)]` would also work.

Comment: If you want to use numpy, then you can also do `df.ix[np.random.choice(df.index, 10)]`.

Comment: Someone in an other post mentioned that `np.random.choice` is twice as fast as `random.sample`

Comment: If you use np.random.choice you have to specify replace=False, otherwise you'll get duplicate rows!

Comment: I think ".ix" is deprecated, and you should use .loc for label based indexing

Comment: See the answer with now over 400 upvotes ... `df_elements = df.sample(n=7)` etc

Answer (score 406):

With pandas version `0.16.1` and up, there is now a `DataFrame.sample` [method built-in](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.np.random.random(100))

# Randomly sample 70% of your dataframe
df_percent = df.sample(frac=0.7)

# Randomly sample 7 elements from your dataframe
df_elements = df.sample(n=7)
```

For either approach above, you can get the rest of the rows by doing:

```
df_rest = df.loc[~df.index.isin(df_percent.index)]
```

Per `Pedram`'s comment, if you would like to get reproducible samples, pass the `random_state` parameter.

```
df_percent = df.sample(frac=0.7, random_state=42)
```

Comment: ``df_0.7`` is not a valid name. Moreover, I suggest replacing ``df_rest = df.loc[~df.index.isin(df_0_7.index)]`` with ``df_rest = df.loc[df.index.difference(df_0_7.index)]``.

Comment: @PietroBattiston Thanks. I was attempting to make the answer clearer, but I agree a non-working example is not clear. Nice with the tip on difference. Though, I still prefer writing the slicing so that I read it as indices "not in the index of my sample". Is there a performance increase with `difference()`?

Comment: @ryanjdillon there was a remaining typo, I fixed it. Concerning the method, I'm actually taking back my suggestion, as indeed it's a bit less efficient. ``df_percent.index.get_indexer(df.index) == -1`` is far more efficient instead (but also more ugly)...

Comment: Nice answer. Also for folks to ensure reproducibility in your code, you might want to add `random_state` to `sample`. E.g., `df_percent = df.sample(frac=0.7, random_state=42)`

Answer (score 53):

#### [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

As of v0.20.0, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), which can be used to return a random sample of a fixed number rows, or a percentage of rows:

```
df = df.sample(n=k)     # k rows
df = df.sample(frac=k)  # int(len(df.index) * k) rows
```

For reproducibility, you can specify an integer `random_state`, equivalent to using [`np.ramdom.seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html). So, instead of setting, for example, `np.random.seed = 0`, you can:

```
df = df.sample(n=k, random_state=0)
```

Answer (score 12):

The best way to do this is with the sample function from the random module,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import sample

# given data frame df

# create random index
rindex =  np.array(sample(xrange(len(df)), 10))

# get 10 random rows from df
dfr = df.ix[rindex]
```

Answer (score 5):

Below line will randomly select n number of rows out of the total existing row numbers from the dataframe df without replacement.

```py
df = df.take(np.random.permutation(len(df))[:n])
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually this will give you repeated indices `np.random.random_integers(0, len(df), N)` where `N` is a large number.