# How to randomly select rows from a data set using pandas?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a data set with 36k rows. I want to randomly select 9k rows from it using pandas. How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I will do it. I have clicked on up arrow. i hope u received the upvote :-)

Comment: Thanks.. you did it right ;-)

Comment: Really a dupe of this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923826/random-row-selection-in-pandas-dataframe see last answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you can use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) - `9k` or `25%` rows:

```
df.sample(n=9000)
```

Or:

```
df.sample(frac=0.25)
```

Another solution with creating random sample of `index` by [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and then select by `loc` - `index` has to be unique:

```
df = df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index, size=9000)]
```

Solution if not unique index:

```
df = df.iloc[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(df)), size=9000)]
```

Comment: how to get the complement?

Answer (score 7):

`numpy`

```
i = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(df)))
idx = i[:9000]
pd.DataFrame(df.values[idx], df.index[idx])
```