# Sampling rows with sample size greater than length of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

I'm being asked to generate a new variable based on the data from an old one.  Basically, what is being asked is that I take values at random (by using the `random` function) from the original one and have at least 10x as many observations as the old one, and then save this as a new variable.

This is my dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv

The variable I wanna work with, is `area`

This is my attempt but it is giving me a `module object is not callable` error:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rand

dataFrame = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv")

area = dataFrame['area']

random_area = rand(area)

print(random_area)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923826/random-row-selection-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @vigneshkrishnan Sorry but that does not answer this question, the sample size is greater than the population size. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) function with `replace=True`:

```
df = df.sample(n=len(df) * 10, replace=True)
```

Or, to sample *only* the area column, use

```
area = df.area.sample(n=len(df) * 10, replace=True)
```

---

Another option would involve [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), and would look something like:

```
df = df.iloc[np.random.choice(len(df), len(df) * 10)]
```

The idea is to generate random indices from 0-`len(df)-1`. The first argument specifies the upper bound and the second (`len(df) * 10`) specifies the number of indices to generate. We then use the generated indices to index into `df`.

If you just want to get the `area`, this is sufficient.

```
area = df.iloc[np.random.choice(len(df), len(df) * 10), df.columns.get_loc('area')]
```

`Index.get_loc` converts the "area" label to position, for `iloc`.

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aab'), 'B': list('123')})
df
   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  3

# Sample 3 times the original size
df.sample(n=len(df) * 3, replace=True)

   A  B
2  b  3
1  a  2
1  a  2
2  b  3
1  a  2
0  a  1
0  a  1
2  b  3
2  b  3

df.iloc[np.random.choice(len(df), len(df) * 3)]

   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  2
1  a  2
0  a  1
2  b  3
0  a  1
0  a  1
0  a  1
2  b  3
```

Comment: Btw.  About the code: `df.sample(n=len(df) * 10, replace=True)`.  Why are you multiplying the entire dataset by 10?

Comment: @OnurOzbek I am not multiplying the dataset by 10, I am specifying the sample size to be len(df) times 10 since your requirement was " have at least 10x as many observations as the old one"

Comment: @OnurOzbek, Re: "You need to explain the syntax". There are better ways to *request help from volunteers*. For example, "please can you explain how `iloc` and `get_loc` work"? You're lucky coldspeed has responded, I would be *less* likely to respond to such a comment from a user.

Comment: Thanks, @coldspeed.  I've already accepted your answer.  I appreciate it.