# Randomly Select Rows in Pandas DataFrame Vectorized Operation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select a random row during a vector operation on a DataFrame. this is what my `inpDF` looks like:

```
    string1    string2
0   abc        dfe
1   ghi        jkl
2   mno        pqr
3   stu        vwx
```

I'm trying to find the function `getRandomRow()` here:

```py
outDF['string1'] = inpDF['string1']
outDF['string2'] = inpDF.getRandomRow()['string2']
```

so that the `outDF` ends up looking (for example) like this:

```
    string1    string2
0   abc        jkl
1   ghi        pqr
2   mno        dfe
3   stu        pqr
```

**EDIT 1:**

I tried using the `sample()` function as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923826/random-row-selection-in-pandas-dataframe), but that just causes the same sample to get replicated accross all rows:

```py
outDF['string1'] = inpDF['string1']
outDF['string2'] = inpDF.sample(n=1).iloc[0,:]['string2']
```

which gives:

```
    string1    string2
0   abc        pqr
1   ghi        pqr
2   mno        pqr
3   stu        pqr
```

**EDIT 2:**

For my particular use case, even picking the value from 'n' rows down would suffice. So, I tried doing this (I'm using `inpDF.index` based on what I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658240/getting-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-pandas-apply-function)):

```py
numRows = len(inpDF)

outDF['string1'] = inpDF['string1']
outDF['string2'] = inpDF.iloc[(inpDF.index + 2)%numRows,:]['string2']
```

but it just ends up picking the value from the same row, and the `outDF` comes out to be this:

```
    string1    string2
0   abc        dfe
1   ghi        jkl
2   mno        pqr
3   stu        vwx
```

whereas I'm expecting it should be this:

```
    string1    string2
0   abc        pqr
1   ghi        vwx
2   mno        dfe
3   stu        jkl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for this:

```
df['string2'] = df.string2.sample(len(df.string2)).to_list()

print(df)
  string1 string2
0     abc     vwx
1     ghi     jkl
2     mno     def
3     stu     pqr
```

Or

```
df['string2'] = df.string2.sample(len(df.string2)).values
```

Comment: If I don't add the `to_list()` or the `values`, I get the values from that row un-shuffled...why is that?

Comment: Might be a bit confusing in `pandas`, but we can refer to a column with brackets like this: `df['string2']` or with the dot-notation like this `df.string2`. Both are the same. Its what you prefer @shinvu

Comment: Goed question @shinvu I was wondering this myself while answering your question. I just posted this is a new question, you can follow it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401864/why-does-my-new-column-does-net-get-assigned-after-using-sample-method

Answer (score 1):

try [`np.random.shuffle()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

```
np.random.shuffle(df.string2)
print(df)

  string1 string2
0     abc     pqr
1     ghi     vwx
2     mno     def
3     stu     jkl
```

If you don't want to shuffle inplace try:

```
df['string3']=np.random.permutation(df.string2)
print(df)
```

Comment: Nice answer with `np.random.shuffle` +1