# Why does my new column does net get assigned after using .sample method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample

So I was just answering a question and I came across something interesting:

The dataframe looks like this:

```
  string1 string2
0     abc     def
1     ghi     jkl
2     mno     pqr
3     stu     vwx
```

So when I do the following, the assigning of new columns works:

```
df['string3'] = df.string2

print(df)

  string1 string2 string3
0     abc     def     def
1     ghi     jkl     jkl
2     mno     pqr     pqr
3     stu     vwx     vwx
```

But when I use `pandas.DataFrame.Series.sample`, the new column does net get assigned, at least not the `sampled` one:

```
df['string4'] = df.string2.sample(len(df.string2))
print(df)
  string1 string2 string3 string4
0     abc     def     def     def
1     ghi     jkl     jkl     jkl
2     mno     pqr     pqr     pqr
3     stu     vwx     vwx     vwx
```

So I tested some things:

**Test1**
Using sample without assign, gives us correct output:

```
df.string2.sample(len(df.string2))

2    pqr
1    jkl
0    def
3    vwx
Name: string2, dtype: object
```

**Test2**
Cannot overwrite either:

```
df['string2'] = df.string2.sample(len(df.string2))
print(df)
  string1 string2
0     abc     def
1     ghi     jkl
2     mno     pqr
3     stu     vwx
```

**This works** but why?

```
df['string2'] = df.string2.sample(len(df.string2)).values
print(df)
  string1 string2
0     abc     jkl
1     ghi     def
2     mno     vwx
3     stu     pqr
```

Why do I need to explicitly use `.values` or `.tolist()` to get the assigning correct?

Comment: Intrinsic Data Alignment... When use sample you are returning a pd.Series with indexes.  So, pandas will align indexes.   When you use .values, you are stripping the index and returning the values.  Hence, pandas is just using ordering to assign the values.

Comment: Googled something new today, `intrinsic data alignment`. Thank you for the infomation. @ScottBoston

Comment: [data alignment is intrinsic](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures)  One of the core tenets of Pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` is `index` sensitive , which means they check the `index` when `assign` it , that is when you do the `serise` assign , the whole df not change , since the `index` is not change , after `sort_index`, it still show the same order of `values`, but if you do the `numpy` `array` assignment , the `index` will not be considered , so that the value itself will be assign back to the original `df` , which yield the output

An example of egde

```
df['string3']=pd.Series(['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa'],index=[100,111,112,113])
df
Out[462]: 
  string1 string2 string3
0     abc     vwx     NaN
1     ghi     jkl     NaN
2     mno     dfe     NaN
3     stu     pqr     NaN
```

---

Because of that index sensitive when you do condition assignment with`.loc`

You can always do

```
df.loc[df.condition,'value']=df.value*100 
# since the not selected one will not be change
```

Just same to what you do with `np.where`

```
df['value']=np.where(df.condition,df.value*100 ,df.value)
```

---

Some other use case 
when I do `groupby` `apply` with none-agg function and try to assign it back ,why  it is failed

> `df['String4']=df.groupby('string1').apply(lambda x :x['string2']+'aa')`
>
> TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Let us try to look at the return of `groupby.apply`

```
df.groupby('string1').apply(lambda x : x['string2']+'aa')
Out[466]: 
string1   
abc      0    vwxaa
ghi      1    jklaa
mno      2    dfeaa
stu      3    pqraa
Name: string2, dtype
```

Notice here it add the one more level into the index , so the return is multiple index ,and original df only have one dimension which will cause the error message .

---

How to fix it ?

---

`reset` the `index` and using the original index which is the second level of the `groupby` product , then assign it back

```
df['String4']=df.groupby('string1').apply(lambda x : x['string2']+'aa').reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df
Out[469]: 
  string1 string2 string3 String4
0     abc     vwx     NaN   vwxaa
1     ghi     jkl     NaN   jklaa
2     mno     dfe     NaN   dfeaa
3     stu     pqr     NaN   pqraa
```

---

As Erfan mentioned in the comment, how can we forbidden accidentally assign unwanted value to `pandas.DataFrame`

Two different ways of assign .

1st, with a array or list or tuple .. CANNOT ALIGN, which means when you have different length between df and assign object , it will fail

2nd assign with `pandas` `object`, ALWAYS aligns, no error will return, even the length different

However when the assign object have duplicated index , it will raise the error

> ```
> df['string3']=pd.Series(['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa'],index=[100,100,100,100])
> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
> ```

Comment: @Erfan I really like the question  , it is not only for the `resample` , but for lot of other use case , I will try to complete more user case as far as I can

Comment: I see. I would be really interested. Please let me know when you did. Thank you for sharing knowledge.

Comment: I have to say, one point is still weird if you ask me. When I use `df['string4'] = df.string2.sample(len(df.string2))`. It does not assign anything, because of the not alligning index as I understood now, but it should throw an error, right now it does nothing basically. Here in this small dataframe we can see it immediately, but in bigger ones this could go unnoticed.

Comment: @Erfan you can think about the assign of df , is more like a left join base on the index

Comment: @Wen-Ben very nice examples. :)

Comment: Valueable information. You can make a Q&A out of this so others will benefit as well.

Comment: @Erfan leave here is fine：-）

Answer (score 3):

That is because the index is still the same, try with `reset_index`:

```
df.string2=df.string2.sample(len(df.string2)).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

  string1 string2
0     abc     jkl
1     ghi     pqr
2     mno     vwx
3     stu     vwx
```

On the other hand, `.values` has just the values with no index, so that works

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Makes sense now!