# Applying function with multiple args including value from previous row on a groupby in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data in a dataframe named "td":

```
bookingID          Speed
---------          ------
000000001          10
000000002          20
000000001          30
000000003          40
000000001          50
```

Basically I need to compute the acceleration for each of the bookingID, so the output must look like this:

```
bookingID          Speed     Acceleration
---------          ------    ------------
000000001          10        0
000000002          20        0
000000001          30        20
000000003          40        0
000000001          50        20
```

for some reason this code does not work:

```
def get_accel(curr_speed,last_speed):
    return last_speed - curr_speed

td['Acceleration'] = td.groupby(['bookingID']).apply(lambda x: get_accel(td.Speed,td.Speed.shift()))
```

It says

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First base on your output it is a `diff` problem

```
td['Acceleration'] = td.groupby('bookingID').Speed.diff().fillna(0)
```

If the function you apply is diff you can fix it by

```
td['Acceleration']= td.groupby(['bookingID']).apply(lambda x: get_accel(x.Speed,x.Speed.shift())).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Comment: I prefer the latter option since I plan on doing more complex functions.. however I get the following error "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index", should I be using "x" instead of "td" in passing the args to the function?

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck yes

Comment: still I get "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index" error, apparently it does not work with version 0.12, any work around? I'd really like to learn this since I've got more complex functions to define. thanks

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck show me your function , also kindly update your pandas

Comment: this is the function: `def get_accel(curr_speed,last_speed):
    return last_speed - curr_speed`

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck try with`td['Acceleration']= td.groupby(['bookingID']).apply(lambda x: get_accel(x.Speed,x.Speed.shift())).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)`

Comment: it worked! would you mind expounding what `reset_index(level=0,drop=True)` does? thanks!!

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck it remove the bookingID from index, since apply create multiple index ,will cause the problem with assign .also , if this help would you like accept it ?

Comment: @chmscrbbrfck additional reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401864/why-does-my-new-column-does-net-get-assigned-after-using-sample-method