# Pandas: .loc not assigning row of one data frame to a row of a slice of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below from which I take a slice called `NDCSPart_df` using `NDCSPart_df = Register_df.iloc[:, :17]`

[image: Register_df]

This `NDCSPart_df` needs to be updated by the latest dataframe `NOTES_df` of same column length but some with different values, and the same or larger number of rows.

I compare a row of `NDCSPart_df` and `NOTES_df` using the "MainDocID" to identify any changes and if there are any changes, the row in `NDCSPart_df` will be assigned the value of the row with the same "MainDocID" in `NOTES_df`.
[image]

```
for i in ChangedDocumentIDDict.keys():    
    NDCSPart_df.loc[NDCSPart_df["MainDocID"]==i,:].update(NOTES_df.loc[NOTES_df["MainDocID"]==i,:])
```

which gives me the following warning,

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:5516:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self[col] = expressions.where(mask, this, that)

Likewise I tried the following code:

```
for i in ChangedDocumentIDDict.keys():
        NDCSPart_df.loc[NDCSPart_df["MainDocID"]==i,:]= NOTES_df.loc[NOTES_df["MainDocID"]==i,:]
```

with similar warning:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:190:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing
>   imports until

But my concern is with the fact that assignment fails with `NaN` values populated which should have values of the row against index 78 of`NOTES_df` as indicated in the second snapshot.

[image]

I am using Python 3.7.3, pandas 0.24.2 and I have tried Python 3.6.6, pandas 0.23.4 with the same results.

My question is:

1. How am I using .loc incorrectly?
2. How can I assign the rows of `NOTES_df` to `NDCSPart_df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like the `index` of two df after filter with condition is different, so we need adding the `.values` more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401864/why-does-my-new-column-does-net-get-assigned-after-using-sample-method)

```
for i in ChangedDocumentIDDict.keys():
        NDCSPart_df.loc[NDCSPart_df["MainDocID"]==i,:]= NOTES_df.loc[NOTES_df["MainDocID"]==i,:].values
```