# Randomly draw a sample for 2 columns

Tags: python, random, sample

A well known function for this in Python is `random.sample()`

However, my dataset consist of multiple columns, and i need the 'lat' and 'lng' coordinates to be sampled. As these two are related, i cannot use the random.sample() separately to get some random lat coordinates + some non corresponding lng coordinates.

What would be the most elegant solution for this?

Perhaps first making a third column, in which i combine lat&lng
Then sample
Then unmerge?

If so, how should i do this, the fact that both lat and lng values are floats with different lengts doesn't make it easier. Probably by adding a'-' in between?

Comment: Aren't you really asking for a random *row* (which contains a lat and a lng)?

Comment: Somthing like that, except for the fact that i don't need a single one, but i need to sample a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you're talking about sampling an entire *row* which has values `[lat_i, lng_i]`. This leads to a very simple (but perhaps too verbose) solution:

```
random_row_index = random.randint(0, number_of_rows_in_dataset - 1)
random_row = dataset[randon_row_index, :]
```

If you have a Pandas dataframe, simply use [`DataFrame.sample`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923826/random-row-selection-in-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: I do use Pandas, df.sample seems to work perfectly! Thanks! What is the difference with "random.sample()" though? isn't the df.sample() random?

Comment: @Cornelis, `df.sample` is Pandas-specific. You can sample your dataframe in less than 20 characters of code, while with `random.sample` you'd have to fiddle with a random index, like I show in my answer, which could look unnecessarily complicated. But indeed, `random.sample`, `numpy.random.sample` and `df.sample` essentially accomplish the same task, so they're similar.

Answer (score 0):

That is what train_test_split is made for: https://realpython.com/train-test-split-python-data/

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y)
```

Comment: Not sure what that does, but it looks interesting... i'll take a look to see how it works. Thanks