# How to read 1 record from a json file using panda

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

In this program I'd like to randomly choose one word from a json file

[My code]

[image: 1]

I succesfully opend the file but i don't know how to access only one record inside "randwords"
Thanks!!!

Comment: `randwords[0]` returns first row , etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random row selection in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923826/random-row-selection-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access a pandas dataframe (the `pd`) with an operation called indexing. For example `pd['data']` will let you have access to the *data* column. Refer to [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) for more information.
One specific function that you can benefit here is `iloc`. For example `pd.iloc[0]` will let you have access to the first *row*. Then you can specify which column you are interested int by calling the appropriate column name.

```
pd.idloc[0].data
```

This will return the *data* column of the first row. Using a random number instead of *0* will result in a random row obioulsy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
randwords.sample(1)
```

See:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html